# MySQL same Query multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I need to query different tables that have the same columns but different content.

Table A:

```
ID   DocDate     Type
1   2013-05-01    A
2   2013-05-01    B
3   2013-05-02    D
4   2013-05-04    D
```

Table B:

```
ID   DocDate     Type
1   2013-05-01    F
2   2013-05-03    G
3   2013-05-03    G
4   2013-05-05    H
```

What I need:

```
COUNT(Tablea.ID)  COUNT(Tableb.ID) DocDate
      2                   1      2013-05-01
      1                  NULL    2013-05-02
     NULL                 2      2013-05-03
      1                  NULL    2013-05-04
     NULL                 1      2013-05-05
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In one query? if so, what is the relation between them?

Comment: Can you show us the query you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT d.docdate, a.total totala, b.total totalb
  FROM
(
  SELECT docdate 
    FROM tablea
   UNION
  SELECT docdate 
    FROM tableb
) d LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT docdate, COUNT(*) total
    FROM tablea
   GROUP BY docdate
) a ON d.docdate = a.docdate LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT docdate, COUNT(*) total
    FROM tableb
   GROUP BY docdate
) b ON d.docdate = b.docdate
 ORDER BY d.docdate
```

Output:

```
|    DOCDATE | TOTALA | TOTALB |
--------------------------------
| 2013-05-01 |      2 |      1 |
| 2013-05-02 |      1 | (null) |
| 2013-05-03 | (null) |      2 |
| 2013-05-04 |      1 | (null) |
| 2013-05-05 | (null) |      1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63610/6)** demo

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get this result.

The most efficient query to return the specified rows is likely going to be:

```
SELECT NULLIF(SUM(c.cnt_a_id),0) AS cnt_a_id
     , NULLIF(SUM(c.cnt_b_id),0) AS cnt_b_id
     , c.DocDate
  FROM (
         SELECT COUNT(a.ID) AS cnt_a_id
              , 0           AS cnt_b_id 
              , a.DocDate   AS DocDate
           FROM Table_A a
          GROUP BY a.DocDate
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 0
              , COUNT(b.ID)
              , b.DocDate
           FROM Table_B b
          GROUP BY b.DocDate
       ) c
 GROUP BY c.DocDate
```

Suitable covering indexes on `(DocDate, ID)` of each table will benefit performance on large sets.

Another simpler to understand, but more expensive, would be create the UNION of the tables, and then perform the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(c.a_id)) AS cnt_a_id
     , NULLIF(COUNT(c.b_id)) AS cnt_b_id
     , c.DocDate
  FROM (
         SELECT a.ID       AS a_id
              , NULL + 0   AS b_id
              , a.DocDate  AS DocDate
           FROM Table_A a
          UNION ALL
         SELECT NULL + 0   AS a_id
              , b.ID       AS b_id
              , b.DocDate  AS DocDate
           FROM Table_B b
       ) c
 GROUP BY c.DocDate
```

(This second query is less efficient, because of the way MySQL materializes the query in the inline view as a temporary MyISAM table; this second query basically creates a copy of Table_A and Table_B concatenated together, and runs a query against that.

The first query is little different, in that it produces smaller sets to be concatenated together.